# How to Switch through Generic @ObservedObject in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui

**Context**

I have a generic `SwiftUI View` that should display different elements depending on the `Generic Type`. However, I get the following error with the implementation below:

> Cannot find '$entityA' in scope

---

**Code**

```swift
class EntityA: Entity, NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}

class EntityB: Entity, NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var isOn: Bool
}

struct RootView<E: Entity>: View {
    @ObservedObject var entity: E
    
    var body: some View {
        switch entity {
            case let entityA as EntityA:
                TextField("Name", text: $entityA.name) // Error
            case let entityB as EntityB:
                Toggle("Enabled", isOn: $entityB.isOn) // Error
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

It seems to me like when binding the specific `Entity` to a constant it loses it's `@ObservedObject` modifier and therefore cannot be passed inside `TextField` or `Toggle`.

- How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another subview where you can observe the specific entity.

```
struct EntityAView: View {
    @ObservedObject var entity: EntityA
    
    var body: some View {

         TextField("Name", text: $entity.name)
        }
    }
}




struct RootView<E: Entity>: View {
    @ObservedObject var entity: E
    
    var body: some View {
        switch entity {
            case let entityA as EntityA:
                EntityAView(entity: entityA)
            case let entityB as EntityB:
                EntityBView(entity: entityB)
        }
    }
}
```